# Add a value to a list of paired values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an array that has pairs of numbers representing row, col values in a model domain. I am trying to add the layer value to have a list of lay, row, col.

I have an array rowcol:

```
array([(25, 65), (25, 66), (25, 67), (25, 68), (26, 65), (26, 66),
       (26, 67), (26, 68), (26, 69), (27, 66), (27, 67), (27, 68),
       (27, 69), (28, 67), (28, 68)], dtype=object)
```

and I want to add an 8 to each pair so it looks like

```
array([(8, 25, 65), (8, 25, 66), (8, 25, 67), (8, 25, 68), (8, 26, 65), (8, 26, 66),
       (8, 26, 67), (8, 26, 68), (8. 26, 69), (8, 27, 66), (8, 27, 67), (8, 27, 68),
       (8, 27, 69), (8, 28, 67), (8, 28, 68)], dtype=object)
```

I created a new array (layer) that was the same length as rowcol and zipped the 2 with:

layrowcol = list(zip(layer, rowcol))

and ended up with:

```
[(8, (25, 65)), (8, (25, 66)), (8, (25, 67)), (8, (25, 68)), (8, (26, 65)), (8, (26, 66)), (8, (26, 67)), (8, (26, 68)), (8, (26, 69)), (8, (27, 66)), (8, (27, 67)), (8, (27, 68)), (8, (27, 69)), (8, (28, 67)), (8, (28, 68))]
```

So it sort of worked and yet didn't quite. Is there a way to combine them and leave out the unwanted parentheses or some better way to add the layer value to each pair without using zip(). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Array of objects are inefficient (not vectorized) and not the common way to use Numpy. Please avoid them if possible. Alternatively, it is better to use list if you cannot. An array of tuples of the same size is typically better as a 2D array. Adding a new column on a Numpy array is simple and fast. Doing that with tuple requires a slow list comprehension + a conversion back to Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([(25, 65), (25, 66), (25, 67), (25, 68), (26, 65), (26, 66),(26, 67), (26, 68), (26, 69), (27, 66), (27, 67), (27, 68),(27, 69), (28, 67), (28, 68)], dtype=object)
>>> b = np.insert(a, 0, 8, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[8, 25, 65],
       [8, 25, 66],
       [8, 25, 67],
       [8, 25, 68],
       [8, 26, 65],
       [8, 26, 66],
       [8, 26, 67],
       [8, 26, 68],
       [8, 26, 69],
       [8, 27, 66],
       [8, 27, 67],
       [8, 27, 68],
       [8, 27, 69],
       [8, 28, 67],
       [8, 28, 68]], dtype=object)
```

If you want back to the `list` of `tuple`s.

```
>>> list(map(tuple, b))
[(8, 25, 65),
 (8, 25, 66),
 (8, 25, 67),
 (8, 25, 68),
 (8, 26, 65),
 (8, 26, 66),
 (8, 26, 67),
 (8, 26, 68),
 (8, 26, 69),
 (8, 27, 66),
 (8, 27, 67),
 (8, 27, 68),
 (8, 27, 69),
 (8, 28, 67),
 (8, 28, 68)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

`*` operator infront of a tuple unpacks it to its constituents.
I am using list comprehension to iterate over each element of input array and create a new tuple out of it with 8 in the beginning.

```
arr = np.array([(25, 65), (25, 66), (25, 67), (25, 68), (26, 65), (26, 66),
       (26, 67), (26, 68), (26, 69), (27, 66), (27, 67), (27, 68),
       (27, 69), (28, 67), (28, 68)], dtype=object)
out = np.array([(8,*x) for x in arr])
out = list(map(tuple,out))
```

Output:

```
[(8, 25, 65), (8, 25, 66), (8, 25, 67), (8, 25, 68), (8, 26, 65), (8, 26, 66),
       (8, 26, 67), (8, 26, 68), (8. 26, 69), (8, 27, 66), (8, 27, 67), (8, 27, 68),
       (8, 27, 69), (8, 28, 67), (8, 28, 68)]
```

Comment: I stsnd corrected.